# How to extend Entity from EF?

Tags: entity-framework-4

All entity created by EF is partial class. so it is extendable. Suppose I have entity Person like

```
partial class Person{FirstName, LastName, .....}
```

Then I want to add a compute property Name like:

```
partial class Person{

[DataMember]        
public string Name
{
   get { return String.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName); }
}

partial void OnFirstNameChanged()
{
  //.....
  this.ReportPropertyChanged("Name");
}

partial void OnLastNameChanged()
{
  //.....
  this.ReportPropertyChanged("Name");
}
//....
}
```

Then for data upate operation I got following error:
The property 'Name' does not have a valid entity mapping on the entity object. For more information, see the Entity Framework documentation.

How to fix this solution?

Comment: Were you trying to do this for UI binding?  If so, what did you end up doing so that it works?  Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is with those `ReportPropertyChanged("Name")`, you are reporting to *ObjectStateManager* that the "Name" property has been changed, while this property does not exists in your model metadata (it has just been declared in your partial class, *ObjectContext* and *ObjectStateManager* do not know anything about this property). 

If you add those `OnLastNameChanged` and `OnFirstNameChanged` partial methods, just get rid of them, you don't need them.

Comment: What do you have to do then so that if there is a WPF control that is bound to a collection of Person and the control shows the computed Name property that that column gets updated in the UI if first or last name change?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same error.
Do not use "ReportPropertyChanged()" but "OnPropertyChanged()" instead. There you go.

ReportPropertyChanged() only works for real entity objects (like FirstName and LastName that are e.g. real database fields), but not those computed ones (like Name, which only exists in your partial class).