# Extending an Entity, error on ReportPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception

I am trying to find out how to extend an Entity by adding a property based on calculations. In the example below I created a MyProperty property that I attribute to the current number of seconds (as an example). However when I try to trigger "ReportPropertyChanged" to raise the envent notification I get an error.

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public double MyCustomizedProperty { get; set; }

    public MyEntity()
    {
        this.PropertyChanged += Entity_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void Entity_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName )
        {
            case "Date":
                MyCustomizedProperty = DateTime.Now.Second;
                ReportPropertyChanged("MyCustomizedProperty");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

That compiles and all, but when I change "Date" I get a runtime error :

> The property 'MyCustomizedProperty' does not have a valid entity mapping on the entity object. For more information, see the Entity Framework documentation.

I suppose this is due to the fact that the property is not in the OnStateManager. Can you please let me know how to fix that ?

Thanks

Comment: I posted an answer to the same issue here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29696057/1059716

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and use it's event to report the Property Change.

Try to use this in your partial class:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler NewPropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = NewPropertyChanged;
    if (null != handler)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And in your property change call it with the properties name

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("YourPropertiesName");
```

Comment: This is a partial extension to an entity class deriving from an entity, doesn't it already have the proper interface ? just to confirm the other data properties don't have any problem
I added the interface but I still have the same problem fyi

Comment: Yes the Entity class should have the proper interface. I didn't notice that you have a partial class. Then you should try to trigger a PropertyChanged event manually and not using the Entities ReportPropertyChanged method.

Comment: What's the best way to do this ? By the way am I missing something or doesn't it seem awfully complicated ?